# Como ler linha a linha de um arquivo e cortar pedaços da string resultante de cada linha?

Tags: c, linux

Tenho esse codigo em C que recebe um ficheiro txt onde nesse ficheiro tem caminhos para arquivos (/Desktop/imagem.png) um por linha.
preciso pegar apenas a parte da extensao do arquivo, o problema é que meu codigo está lendo apenas a primeira linha do arquivo txt, como posso fazer para ele ler todas as linhas ?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < quant_linhas; i++)
        {
            FILE *arq;
            char Linha[100];

            arq = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
            fgets(Linha, 100, arq);
            printf("Linha : %s", Linha);
            //fgets(Linha, 100, arq);

            char *substring;
            char *extensao = strrchr(Linha, '.');
            char *extensao1 = extensao + 1;
            char extensaoFinal[strlen(extensao1) + 1];
            strcpy(extensaoFinal, extensao1);
            printf("%s\n", extensaoFinal);
}
```

extensaoFinal Resulta na extensao do arquivo, porém a saida está sendo essa:

```
Linha : /home/user/Desktop/testeF.png
png
Linha : /home/user/Desktop/testeF.png
png
```

Sendo que meu teste.txt (arquivo onde passo os diretorios tem isso):

```
/home/user/Desktop/testeF.png
/home/user/Desktop/testeV.jpeg
```

a minha funcao quantidade de linhas tem essa estrutura :

```
int quantidadeLinhas()
{ // retorna a quantidade de linhas de um arquivo txt
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    int caractere = 0;
    int quant_linhas = 1;

    while ((caractere = fgetc(arquivo)) != EOF)
    {
        if (caractere == '\n')
        {
            quant_linhas++;
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    return quant_linhas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

você colocou essas variáveis

```
for (int i = 0; i < quant_linhas; i++)
{
    FILE *arq;                    // cria uma variavel tipo ponteiro 
    char Linha[100];              // cria uma variavel string

    arq = fopen("teste.txt", "r");// abre o arquivo a cada passo
    fgets(Linha, 100, arq);       // le o arquivo a partir do inicio dele
                                  // e não fecha o arquivo ,
```

dentro do loop for , assim ele abre o arquivo a cada passo do loop .    e lê o arquivo novamente desde o início .  e não precisa saber o número de linhas do arquivo , você pode colocar a leitura do arquivo como condição do while até que encontre o fim do arquivo , não importando quantas Linhas ele tenha :

```
while(fgets(linha,100,arq) != NULL)
{
    printf("Linha : %s", Linha);
```

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma função `feof` para a manipulação de arquivos que indica o final do arquivo (ou *end of file*), que você pode colocar como condição em um `while` para que o arquivo seja lido até o final. Como a `feof` indica o final do arquivo, pode colocar `while(!feof(<nome_do_arquivo>)`, que seria executar o laço enquanto o arquivo não chegar ao fim.

Você pode colocar esse trecho de código

```
     fgets(Linha, 100, arq);
     printf("Linha : %s\n", Linha);
         //fgets(Linha, 100, arq);

     char *substring;
     char *extensao = strrchr(Linha, '.');
     char *extensao1 = extensao + 1;
     char extensaoFinal[strlen(extensao1) + 1];
     strcpy(extensaoFinal, extensao1);
     printf("%s\n", extensaoFinal);
```

dentro de um laço, para que o arquivo seja lido até o final. Ficaria algo como:

```
while(!feof(arq)){
        fgets(Linha, 100, arq);
        printf("Linha : %s\n", Linha);
            //fgets(Linha, 100, arq);

        char *substring;
        char *extensao = strrchr(Linha, '.');
        char *extensao1 = extensao + 1;
        char extensaoFinal[strlen(extensao1) + 1];
        strcpy(extensaoFinal, extensao1);
        printf("%s\n", extensaoFinal);
    }
```

Isso vai permitir que todas as linhas do seu arquivo sejam lidas.